# Is there a LINQ way to iterate through an array of strings?

Tags: c#, .net

I have an array of strings like this:

```
test[1] = "AA";
test[2] = "BB";
```

I like to do things in good ways. Now I need to iterate through the array so it looks like this:

```
1. "AA"
2. "BB"
etc ..
```

I think I can do this with a for loop and index but I am wondering if I can also do it with LINQ.

Comment: Without knowing what you actually want to do its hard to suggest a solution.

Comment: Nice answer from @polishchuk. Why would you jump into LINQ for something as simple as this? Using LINQ will generate a new IEnumerable - so you will have two instances of your list floating around, which becomes problematic if you are dealing with a very large array. LINQ is great, but it isn't the solution to every little iteration problem, there is still a place for a simple `for` loop.

Comment: If I didn't use LINQ then can I do it really easy with another way?

Comment: Simple `for` loop: `for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++) arr[i] = string.Format("{0}. {1}", i+1, arr[i]);`. It's all good if you are simply learning how to use LINQ, but sometimes there is nothing wrong with the basics...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Prior to C# 6.0:

```
var result = test.Select((s, i) => string.Format("{0}. {1}", i + 1, s));
```

Starting from C# 6.0 you can use interpolated strings:

```
var result = test.Select((s, i) => $"{i + 1}. {s}");
```

Comment: I get a message "does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type". If I don't use LINQ how I could I do this?

Comment: You are missing `using System.Linq;`

Comment: @polishchuk Nice. The only thing I miss is `++i` instead of `i + 1` ;-)